# Get full user name and e-mail as stored in KDE system settings

Tags: bash, kubuntu, kde

Kubuntu/KDE stores the full user name and the e-mail adress of each user. They can be viewed and edited using the corresponding system settings dialog.

Is there a (KDE specific) way to get both information using a bash command?

Comment: try the package `finger`

Comment: @PRATAP Doesn't work. "No mail." but the address is visible in the KDE settings panel.

Comment: 0h sorry.. I don't know other way..